# How to assign validations for model and controller in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing the one register form.but i dont know how to do the validations in cakephp for that register form in controller class.

**model class:**

**user.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel
{
var $name='User';
//var $useTable = false;
var $validate= array(
        'username'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'required'=>true,
                'message'=>'Enter your name'
        ),
        'email'=>array(
                'email'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'email',
                        'message'=>'Enter a valid emial address'
                ),
                'email'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                        'required'=>true,
                        'message'=>'Enter your email address'
                )

        ),

        'password'=>array(
                'alphaNumeric' => array(
                        'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                        'required' => true,
                        'message' => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
                ),
                'password' => array(
                        'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
                        'message' => 'Minimum 8 characters long'
                ),
               ),
        'firstname'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'required'=>true,
                'message'=>'Enter your firstname'
        ),
        'lastname'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'required'=>true,
                'message'=>'Enter your lastname'
        ),
);
```

**controller class:

UserController.php**

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Users';    

    function send(){
        if(!empty($this->data)){
            $this->User->set($this->data);
            if($this->User->validates()){
                if(!empty($this->data['User']['username'])) {
                    $this->username->from = $this->data['User']['username'] ;
                }
                else{
                    $this->username->from = $this->data['User']['username'] .
                    ' <' . $this->data['User']['username'] . '>';
                    $this->render('success');
                }
            }
            else {
                $this->render('register');
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

**Users.register view**
**register.ctp**

```
<h3>Registration Form<h3>
    <form action="../users/register" method="POST" name="form">
    UserName:<input type="text" name="username">
    Password:<input type="password" name="password">
    Email:<input type="text" name="email">
    FirstName:<input type="text" name="firstname">
    LastName:<input type="text" name="lastname">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

please help me how to do the validations in cakephp.

Comment: what you do is redundant code- look at you function

Comment: validations are not performed for this register form.

Comment: do NOT change the original question

Comment: Please do the blog tutorial before continuing (do, don't just read it). Not using the form helper is a big factor in why it "doesn't work".

Comment: @issac it IS desirable for questions to be edited adding further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an action named register() and created a view register.ctp.
Your register aciton code looks like that-

```
function register(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $this->User->create();
        if($this->User->save($this->data)){
                 $this->Session->setFlash("User saved!");
                $this->redirect('/login');
            }
            else{
                 $this->Session->setFlash("Unable to save now, Try later!");
            }
        }
 }
```

Now when you try to save data, your data will validate automatically if you define validate rules on model.

Comment: but it not working.i already created register.ctp class .but this function is not working.please write total code,how to do the validation for register form

Answer (score 0):

in your code you haven't written any code for data save.....if you will save or edit data..your model will take care of validation automatically as you have written var $validate
in your model code..........

Comment: i am new to cakephp,i dont know how to do the validations.please tell me the entire process for above code

Answer (score 0):

1. when you want to save your data you will need to assign the validation. true activates the validation. how ever in default validation is set to true.

   ```
   $this->User->save($this->data)
   //to 
   $this->User->save($this->data , true ) //or false - set the validation here

   // your function needs to be public    
   public function register(){
      if(!empty($this->request->data)){        
         if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
               //save data
           else{
               //data didn't save
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. In some cases like create or update you need to set where you want to assign your validation behavior. e.g. on save on create or update.
3. In your model `'required'=>true,` is used for other reason. Use 'rule'=>'notEmpty', is for the inputs that is required
4. **Your Form it's not standard for cakephp validation**: Create your Form and inputs cakephp based so you will have clear code and make the job available for your validation

   ```
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register')));?>
           <fieldset>
                   <legend><?php echo __('Register User'); ?></legend>
                   <div class="seven columns">
           <?php
                   echo $this->Form->input('username');    
                   echo $this->Form->input('password');    
                   echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
                   echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
                   echo $this->Form->input('phone_number');
                   echo $this->Form->input('email');
                   echo $this->Form->input('address1');
                   echo $this->Form->input('address2');
           ?>
                   </div>

           </fieldset>
       </div>

   <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Register'));?>
   ```
5. remove var $name = 'Users';  => this line is already set in default
6. **Model: variables should be public**

   ```
   var $name='User';        
   var $validate= array(); 

   //change them to 

    public $name='User';        
    public $validate= array();
   ```

Comment: Only point 4 is relevant to the problem. Point 1 is not helpful since validation is done by default, if create/update isn't specified (point 2) validation rules apply to all saves, notEmpty and required are not the same thing, point 5 and 6 are of no consequence relating to prior php4 support.